# Can we install Xcode directly on windows?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

I am using flutter with Android studio and I am getting `.apk` files successfully for Android. Now I want to get `.ipa` file as well for `ios`. but I am not able to get Xcode on windows. How can we install Xcode on windows to use with flutter? I have to install Xcode to get `.ipa` file for iOS.

Comment: You can't install Xcode on Winows OS. 
The only solution is to make hackintosh or use virtualbox to run mac OS but that not work well

Comment: But you can give that a [chance](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667).